# Questions about proving $E^H /F$ is a normal extension $\Leftrightarrow$ $H\lhd Gal(E/F)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field, automorphism-group

Here is the proof of $E^H /F$ is a normal extension $\Leftrightarrow$ $H\lhd Gal(E/F)$.(Please zoom in to see the second picture)
[image]
[image]

I cannot understand $2$ of the lines of the proof:

> $1$:[image]
>
> $2$:[image]

I cannot understand(in the second picture) why it is the fact that $(E^H)^{G/H}=E^G=F$ (here we regard $G/H$ as the image of $G/H$ in $Aut_F(E^H)$) and why is the fact that the degree of $E^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}$ is the same as $E^H$.

May I please ask for a more explicit explanation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Being invariant under $G$ is certainly being invariant by $H$ and by elements of $G/H$, and conversely.
As to $E^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}$ this is $\sigma(E^H)$

Comment: @A.Rod So for the second point: Is it the fact that since $\sigma$ is an automorphism, when it acts on $E^H$, $F$ is fixed, and write $E^H=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ denote the generator of $E^H =$ over $F$, we permute these generators and hence get $\sigma(E^H)=F(\beta_1,...,\beta_n)$? But may I please ask for an explaination of why these extensions have yhe same degree?

Comment: @user1952009 It intuitively makes some sence to be, but I have not learnt how to decompose an automorphism and say something about its relation to the quotient group. May I please ask for a proof? Or any reference would be appreciate.

Comment: This is even simpler, if $e\in E^H$ then $\sigma(e)$ is clearly invariant by any element of $\sigma H \sigma^{-1}$ and conversely as $\sigma^{-1}\sigma H\sigma\sigma^{-1}=H$.
Now $\sigma$ is an $F$-linear isomorphism, so it respects the degree over $F$.

Comment: I tried but I think there I have trouble on it. In one of the 2 directions I aim to conclude that $E^H\subseteq E^{\sigma H \sigma^{-1}}$, so I pick any element $e\in E^H$, by definition of $E^H$ I have $\forall h\in H$, $h(\alpha)=\alpha$. Now I want $\sigma h\sigma^{-1}(\alpha)=\alpha$. So does $h(\alpha)=\alpha$ imply $h(\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(\alpha)$? How to see this?

Comment: I never claimed that $E^H$ was (a subset of) $E^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}$.
I claimed that $\sigma(E^H)=E^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}$.
THis is sufficient to ensure that $E^H$ and $E^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}$ have the same degree over $F$ which was your question, wasn't it?

Comment: @A.Rod Oh I misunderstood it, so is this a fact that an automorphism restrict to a subextension is always an $F$-isomorphism? Does it comes from linear algebra: the linear map $\sigma: E^H\rightarrow \sigma(E^H)$ is injective and hence bijective?

Comment: ($\alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha)$ have the same minimal polynomial) If $E^H/F$ is normal then $\alpha \in E^H \implies \sigma(\alpha) \in E^H$  and $h(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(\alpha)$. Conversely if $H$ is a normal subgroup then $E^H = E^{\sigma H  \sigma^{-1}}$

Comment: @user1952009 Oh I think now I have get the second point, thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you asking me why $\sigma: E^H\to \sigma(E^{H})$ is surjective? Are you sure? 
The map $\sigma$ is injective because it is a field morphism and every one of them is injective (a field has no non trivial ideals).

Comment: @A.Rod Oh... It is trivial, forgive me for ask for such a stupid point... Got it. And if possible, could you please give some explaination to the first point? It is still bordering me...

Comment: No problem.
Let's prove that $(E^H)^{G/H}=E^G$, take $e$ in the latter, then $h.e=e$ and thus $\overline{g}.e$ is well defined as is does not depends on the representant of $g$ we choose in $G$, but whichever $g$ we chose in $G$ to represent $\overline{g}$, we will still have $g.e=e$, thus $\overline{g}.e=e$.
Conversely take $e$ in $E^H$ and assume that $e$ is invariant by the action of $G/H$, take $g\in G$, then $g.e=\overline{g}.e$ since this is the definition of the action of $G/H$ on $E^H$, thus $g.e=\overline{g}.e=e$ if $e$ is in $(E^H)^{G/H}$

Comment: @A.Rod May I please ask where do we use the fact that $e$ is in the field that is fixed by $H$ in this argument? I think I have not get the point here.

Comment: Well the fact that $e$ is fixed by $H$ is necessary to define the action of $G/H$ on $e$.
You have an action of $G/H$ over $E^H$ constructed out of the action of $G$ over $E$.

Comment: @A.Rod It is much clearer now. Thanks a lot for patience!

Comment: do you agree with my answer ? @A.Rod

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is what I get from the comments :

Let $E/N/F$ be a field extension such that $E/F$ is Galois.
$N/F$ is a normal extension iff for any $\alpha \in E$ and $\sigma \in Aut(E/F)$, if $\alpha \in N$ then $\sigma(\alpha) \in N$.

Let $G = Aut(E/F)$, $H$ a subgroup, $E^H$ its fixed field.

If $E^H/F$ is normal then for every $\sigma \in G, h \in H$, we have $\alpha \in E^H$ iff $\sigma(\alpha) \in E^H$ so that $h(\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(\alpha)$. Thus $\alpha =\sigma^{-1}(h(\sigma(\alpha)))$ and $\alpha \in E^{\sigma^{-1} H \sigma}$ iff $\alpha \in E^H$. By the Galois correspondence, $E^{\sigma^{-1} H \sigma} = E^H \implies H = \sigma^{-1} H \sigma$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Conversely, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $H = \sigma^{-1} H \sigma$ so that $\alpha \in E^H$ iff $\sigma(\alpha) \in E^H$ and hence $E^H/F$ is normal.

Comment: Latter I realized that there is still left to show that all the roots are $\sigma(\alpha)$ for some $\sigma\in G$. How may I show that we can regard every root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ as some $\sigma (\alpha)$?

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 If $\alpha,\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial then $F(\alpha) \cong F(\beta)$ and this isomorphism extends to the normal closure. You'll also need to prove the Galois conjugates and the Galois correspondence